# How to make VS Code build and run Rust programs?

Tags: rust, visual-studio-code

I've been using [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), and I was wondering how to build a `task.json` file that will have these commands. `cargo build`, `cargo run [ARGS]` `cargo run --release -- [ARGS]`

I've tried making one with the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/tasks) on `task.json`. I kept getting `No such subcommand` errors.

Sample:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
// The command is tsc. Assumes that tsc has been installed using npm install -g typescript
"command": "cargo",

// The command is a shell script
"isBuildCommand": true,

// Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur. 
"showOutput": "silent",

"tasks": [{
   "taskName": "run test",
   "version": "0.1.0",
   "command": "run -- --exclude-dir=node_modules C:/Users/Aaron/Documents/Github/",
   "isShellCommand": true,
   "showOutput": "always"
},
{
   "taskName": "run",
   "version": "0.1.0",
   "args": [  "--"
           , "--exclude-dir=node_modules"
           , "C:/Users/Aaron/Documents/Github/"
           ]
   "isShellCommand": true,
   "showOutput": "always"
}]
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can find some inspiration in this reddit thread: http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/389d3o/visual_studio_code_rust_has_been_added_as_a/

Comment: I've deleted my answer, but updated gist (sorry the code was mis-pasted) https://gist.github.com/vilic/f756ccfdb91b004e7a70. The reason why using node to execute another script is that Visual Studio Code problem matcher can not handle multiline errors, so I need to do something intermediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly these answers are out of date, here is my tasks.json, which implements cargo run, cargo build and a cargo command to run the currently open example...

A key thing is to specify the problem matcher, so you can click through errors:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "cargo run example",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cargo run --example ${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$rustc"
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "cargo run",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cargo run",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$rustc"
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "cargo build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cargo build",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$rustc"
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The command property is only supported at the top level. In addition, arguments have to be passed via the args property. If they are put into the command, the command is treated as a command with whitespaces in its name. An example of the run task would look like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "cargo",
    "isShellCommand": true, // Only needed if cargo is a .cmd file
    "tasks": [
        {
           "taskName": "run",
           "args": [
               "--release"
               // More args
           ],
           "showOutput": "always"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I configured my tasks.json file

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "cargo",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["run"],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

Entering the build command (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>) will build and run the code.

Comment: Curious if this still works for anyone or is out of date. On my system it just produces a blank `error:` message